# How to create HTML element with javascript and save it to database MySql

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to save my created element to database. So when i refresh the page the created element still on the page. Please help me, thank you.

```js
document.getElementById("insert").onclick = function(){
  if(document.getElementById('number').value !== ""){
 var a = document.createElement('a');              
    a.className = "button fit icon fa-warning";
 a.href = "tel:" + document.getElementById('number').value;  var c = document.getElementById('nama').value;
 a.innerHTML = c;
      
 var container = document.getElementById('linkcontainer');
 container.appendChild(a);   
  }   
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" value="" placeholder="Input Name" required>
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="" placeholder="Input Number" required>
<button name="insert" id="insert" class="button">Add Number</button>
<div id="linkcontainer"></div>
```

Comment: you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it, but saving it in a database is not one of them. I wouldn't suggest serializing the entire JavaScript code for inserting a new element or even the key parts of the addition to DOM to a database.

Instead, save it in a XML or JSON configuration file and save it on the server side. On every client - server interaction, i.e. whenever you make a call to the server send a new request parameter stating the DOM element, it's parent, it's value, it's class(es), it's id and all the other necessary attributes. Parsing this information, save it in your configuration file. Now before at every load of this page, read your configuration file and change your HTML DOM.

Still, if you want to save it in database please choose a relational database and create a relation having attributes as serial_no, parent_id, attributes (which is a pipe separated key value pairs of attributes and its values). On every request to your backend script,fire queries (use prepared statements only) to save the new information to the database. Read this data on page load and append to HTML DOM.

Hope this helps!